# Pandas: Merge on one column using EXACT match when column values overlap

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to merge based on the values in one Column (SKU). The 'SKU' values are varied. For example, SKU values range from "00047" to "TPA20839". However, they are always alphanumeric.

When the dataframes are read from the csv files, I convert the 'SKU' column to strings so they merge on the same data type. The data merges correctly, EXCEPT when there are overlapping string values.

For example, there is a df_master['SKU'] value = "6748". There are two similar values in df_inv['SKU'] -> "6748" AND "9006748" (two different items, 6748 == 6748 9006784 != 6748).

This causes this row to NOT appear in the new dataframe.

I want it to to EXACT match, similar to the =MATCH('','',0) function in excel. Can you help me achieve this?

```
df_master['SKU'] = df_master['SKU'].astype(str)
df_inv['SKU'] = df_inv['SKU'].astype(str)

df_new = pd.merge(df_inv, df_master, on='SKU')

df_new.to_csv('new-master.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

I think the trick may be to format the data type differently, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't quite see the issue, `9006784 != 6748`, so they definitely shouldn't merge. Is the issue that the row for '90006784` no longer appears in your output becasue it doesn't have a match? The default `merge` is an inner merge, which only keeps rows with keys common to both `DataFrames`. You likely wanted a right merge in this case, given the name `df_master`

Comment: This is it. Can you help me understand it? I read about right, left, inner, outer, but I can't wrap my head around it. Shouldn't both keys show up when I do inner since it's in both DataFrames?

Comment: Update: when you use 'how=right', it will return all the SKUs, but the corresponding values are NaN. This is only for those oddly overlapping str like 9006784 and 6748.

Comment: Merging can only work for exact keys, so 9006748 will not merge with 6748 in another DataFrame. You may know they are the same due to the last 4 digits, but merge cannot. If you need to merge on things like that, you need to use much more sophisticated logic, or if it's always just the last 4 digits, then you can just merge on the last 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vals_matched = []
haystacks = df_inv['SKU'].astype(str).tolist()
needles = df_master['SKU'].astype(str).tolist()

for needle in needles:
    for haystack in haystacks:
        if needle in haystack:
            vals_matched.append(needle)
            break

df_master = df_master[df_master.SKU.astype(str).isin(needles)]
```

The `break` statement continues to the next `needle`, that is, the next value you're trying to match. The reason for that is that a single match is sufficient between two lists.